# Stacked barplot with two categorical variables from dataframe, Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to visualize this plot for some time now, but to no avail. I want to make a stacked barplot where the height of the bar is determined by the % of students (each row) eating the free/reduced lunch (binary variable), and the position of the bar is based on a categorical variable (edu. group). The stacked element of each bar is determined by another categorical variable (race/ethnicity). [image: Dataframe]

Thus i want the bar to look this this:
[image: Desired barplot]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the data and code that will provide the graph you are looking for. The steps done are:

- Calculate the percentages of those using `free/reduced` lunch. This is calculated against each education group and stored in `percs`
- The `totals` column has the count of each education group, which will be used to identify the position of the labels. Note that this count is for those using `free/reduced` lunch option only
- Some consolidation of the data is required. The dataframe is first filtered by the ones using `free/reduced` lunch as this is all you are looking to plot.
- Then it is grouped using `groupby()` by the education group and then the race columns and . This is then `unstacked()`.
- Finally the top level of the columns (lunch) is removed so that the
  legend is cleaner. Do try the group and unstack parts by yourself to
  see how the data is changed to suit the graph
- This data is plotted
- Finally, using the `totals` and `percs`, a label is added on top of each stacked bar to show the percentages. I have used 1 decimal place, but you can adjust it as you need

Note: I am using python `3.8.8` and matplotlib `3.3.4`. If you have matplotlib `3.4.2` or later, you can use matplotlib's [bar_label()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), which might reduce a little effort in plotting the text.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

**My Data**

```
>> df
    parental edu. group race/ethnicity  lunch
0   College edu Group A free/reduced
1   College edu Group A free/reduced
2   College edu Group A free/reduced
3   College edu Group B free/reduced
4   College edu Group B free/reduced
5   College edu Group B standard
6   College edu Group B standard
7   College edu Group A standard
8   College edu Group A standard
9   College edu Group A standard
10  High School Group A free/reduced
11  High School Group A free/reduced
12  High School Group B free/reduced
13  High School Group A standard
14  High School Group B standard
15  No edu  Group B standard
16  No edu  Group A standard
17  No edu  Group B free/reduced
18  No edu  Group A free/reduced
```

**Code**

```
percs=[] ##To store percentages
totals=[] ##To store totals
#Update the totals and percentages for each education-group
for ch in df['parental edu. group'].unique():
    percs.append(round(len(df[(df['lunch']=='free/reduced') & (df['parental edu. group'] == ch)])/len(df[df['parental edu. group'] == ch])*100,1))
    totals.append(len(df[(df['lunch']=='free/reduced') & (df['parental edu. group'] == ch)]))

# Group data, count the lunch column and unstack it
df=df[df['lunch']=='free/reduced'].groupby(['parental edu. group', 'race/ethnicity']).count().unstack('race/ethnicity')

#Drop the top level - lunch
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

#Plot the graph
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0, ax=ax)

# Add labels to each stacked bar. 
# Note that the position is found from totals list and text is from percs list
for i, total in enumerate(totals):
    print(i, totals[i], percs[i]*100)
    ax.text(i, total + 0.1, str(percs[i])+"%", ha='center', weight='bold')
```

[image]

**New Req**

Updated code below. You need to convert the dataframe from numbers to percentages - the 2 for loops will go through each row+column and change it to percentage. Few adjustments in terms of adding % to the y-axis, increasing the height so the annotations show up properly and changing the location of the percentage location are required. See code below.

```
percs=[]
totals=[]
df.sort_values(by=['parental edu. group'], inplace=True) ##Sorted so that grouping won't be an issue later
for ch in df['parental edu. group'].unique():
    percs.append(round(len(df[(df['lunch']=='free/reduced') & (df['parental edu. group'] == ch)])/len(df[df['parental edu. group'] == ch])*100,1))
    totals.append(len(df[(df['lunch']=='free/reduced') & (df['parental edu. group'] == ch)]))

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

df=df[df['lunch']=='free/reduced'].groupby(['parental edu. group', 'race/ethnicity']).count().unstack('race/ethnicity')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

#For each row, col, change absolute value to percentage
for row in range(len(df)):
    for col in df.columns:
        df.iloc[row, df.columns.get_loc(col)] = df.iloc[row, df.columns.get_loc(col)] * percs[row] / totals[row]

df.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0, ax=ax)
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[1]+5) ## Increase height of the plot
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter()) ##  Add % to the yticks

# Add labels to each bar
for i, total in enumerate(totals):
    print(i, totals[i], percs[i]*100)
    ax.text(i, percs[i] + 2, str(percs[i])+"%", ha='center', weight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the awesome reply. However. this is the result I get: https://imgur.com/a/jyEwHcT
The y axis (height of bars) should represent the education group's percentage of students getting the free/reduced lunch. It's around 35% for all the education groups... Can you fix it, despite my poor communications skills?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to see the link. Currently y-axis shows the count of rows. For college edu row, it is 3 GrpA and 2 GrpB. Are you saying that you want the y-axis to be just % - 0 to 60 or 70%? Would the first bar have 3/10 (30%) for GrpA and 2/10 (20%) for GrpB adding up to 50%? Is that the expectation? Note that the Collge_Edu bar will be shorter than the other two as it is 50%, while the other two will be 60%. Pls confirm

Comment: Hi Redox - y axis should show the percentage of students (within each education) group being assigned the free lunch. This is about 35% pr. education group. If you want to see the data you can find it here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/spscientist/students-performance-in-exams

Yes - the bars would add up to the total percentage (~35% pr education group). Thus for the first bar fx, race group A might account for 40% (of the 35%) and race group B 60% (of the the 35 %). There are a total of 5 race groups. I hope this makes sense and you're ready for the challenge!

Comment: Check new req section for updates requested

Comment: Hi Redox. This was wild! I also did the following to add values with each bar - However, not showing the percentage symbol..
#I used this guide to insert values within the stacked barplot.I set y_offset to -2 https://www.pythoncharts.com/matplotlib/stacked-bar-charts-labels/

Comment: Did it finally work? Still having issues? If yes, let me know what error you are getting

Comment: The last plot in the link has the `%` symbol in y-axis